# Graphical glitches on 20.10 with i915

Tags: video, intel-graphics

From time to time I'm getting graphical glitches. Laptop (Thinkpad T480s) isn't overheated. My video card is integrated Intel UHD Graphics 620.

Replug of USB Type-C dock with an external screen solves the issue for a while, but eventually it comes back.

Can it be a hardware issue?

[The picture of the screen with glitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXVEc.jpg)

Comment: it would be useful if you have any error whatsover to show us in dmesg or the graphical server is installed which could be Xorg or wayland or mutter ? Also if I recall correctly USB-C is proprietary so it could be the fault of the kernel also and so it could vary with the kernel you have. Which graphical drivers do you use? Did you modify it or replace the default one which should be the nouveau driver?

Comment: Dmesg doesn't show any related errors to me. I'm using Xorg. I don't have proprietary drivers on my system. I have default opensource driver.